# How to apply a function on each group of data in a pandas group by

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Suppose the data frame below:

```
|id |day | order |
|---|--- |-------|
| a | 2  |  6    |
| a | 4  |  0    |
| a | 7  |  4    |
| a | 8  |  8    |
| b | 11 | 10    |
| b | 15 | 15    |
```

I want to apply a function to *day* and *order* column of each group by rows on *id* column.
The function is:

```
def mean_of_differences(my_list):
   return sum([ my_list[i] - my_list[i-1] for i in range(1, len(my_list))]) / len(my_list)
```

This function calculates mean of differences of each element and the next one. For example, for id=a, *day* would be **2+3+1 divided by 4**. I know how to use lambda, but didn't find a way to implement this in a pandas group by. Also, each column should be ordered to get my desired output, so apparently it is not possible to sort by one column before group by
The output should be like this:

```
|id |day| order |
|---|---|-------|
| a |1.5|   2   |
| b | 2 |  2.5  |
```

Any one know how to do so in a group by?

Comment: `df.groupby('id')['day'].agg(mean_of_differences)`

Comment: @Cimbali This seems not to work if the day column is not ordered. Suppose if I have more than one column and want to apply similar function on each of them. Can I order each group in that function?

Comment: please edit that into the question, both the order issues (not quite clear what you mean here, according to what should values be sorted?) and several column issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, sort your data by `day` then group by `id` and finally compute your diff/mean.

```
df = df.sort_values('day') \
       .groupby('id') \
       .agg({'day': lambda x: x.diff().fillna(0).mean()}) \
       .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  id  day
0  a  1.5
1  b  2.0
```

Comment: @masoud. Does it answer to your question?

Comment: Actually your answer is Brilliant! But I wonder is it possible to sort rows of each group before using lambda without trying to sort the whole column?

Comment: Yes you can but it's suboptimized: `df = df.groupby('id').agg({'day': lambda x: x.sort_values().diff().fillna(0).mean()}).reset_index()`